# CurrentApp.LicenseInformation only lets me access it once

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I'm having a issue when calling `CurrentApp.LicenseInformation` where the first call gets thru but if i close the app and open again the next call locks the app and it closes. But if i wait 5-10min and open it once more i can once again access it, once.

This is the method that i have at the moment when making the call:

```
public bool HasPurchasedPlus()
{
    var licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;

    var iap1 = licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["Package1"].IsActive;
    var iap2 = licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["Package2"].IsActive;

    return iap1 || iap2;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated to solve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: The codes seems fine. Could you please try it on other devices?

Comment: Looks like it works on my mobile running Win 10 so at the moment it only affects the app running on my desktop. Worth a note is also that i am running insider builds on both the devices:

PC: Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview - Version: 1607 - OS Build: 10.0.14942.1000
Mobile: Windows 10 Mobile - Version: 1607 - OS Build: 10.0.14926.1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a System update the issue has since then disappeared. I can't definitely say it was a OS issue but at the moment it looks like it was due to a issue in reading data from the system since it also affected reading files.